# How to wait all data load ajax complete to render page in Anagular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

In my page, I need a page to load a matrix of data (a table), so I make 3 requests to get all data:

- Columns data
- Rows data
- Relationship data

After has all datas, I using a function `getRelation(columnIndex, rowIndex)` to get relation data.

But when rows are loaded before then columns, Angular will try to execute my `getRelation` method to render, but it will occur an error because has not column data.

Maybe I can just put an `if` condition in my function, but I just want know, has some way better to resolve this situation?

```
this.relations = [];
this.columns = [];
this.rows = [];
this.getRalation = function getRalation(columnIndex, rowIndex) {
    var column= this.columns[columnIndex];
    var row= this.rows[rowIndex]

    var relation = $myService.getSomthing(this.relations, column.ID, row.ID);

    return relation;
}.bind(this);

$http.post(url, {}).then(function(res) {
    this.rows = res.data;
}.bind(this));

// same code for columns and relations
```

Comment: Use ng-show or ng-if

Comment: could you show the code you are using to make your requests

Comment: @Lorenzo I updated my post, putting a request example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service:

```
$q.all([/*promise from row request*/,/*promise from column request*/]).then(function(result){
     var rows = result[0];
     var columns = result[1];
     //parse row and cols, use getRalation here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better If you handle rows calculation after colomns. Try to use promises in javascript. You can use the library Q.

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 0):

As @Vanojx1 sayed, you should use `$q` service which is use to combine promises. Check the [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for more understanding.

```
var rows = $http.post(url, {}).then(function(res) {
    return res.data;
})


var columns = $http.post(url, {}).then(function(res) {
    return res.data;
})

var relationship = $http.post(url, {}).then(function(res) {
    return res.data;
})


var results = [];

$q.all([rows, columns, relationship]).then(function(result){
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        results.push(result[i]);
    }
    result[0] //rows data
    result[1] //columns data
    result[2] //relationship data

});
```